# Using fread to only load datarows available in another dataframe

Tags: r, fread

I have large files (19 million rows x 16 columns) and want to harmonize one such file with a much smaller file (440 rows) using R.

I load the large file using `fread` and then use `data.merge = merge(file1, file, by="car")`. However, to reduce the memory needed in R I would like to avoid loading the whole big file. Is there a way to use `fread` to only load the rows I need (the overlap, e.g. only rows with the same car models in column "car" as file 1)?

**For example:**

```
fread("filepath.file2", by = file1$car)
```

Comment: Take a look at the package `vroom`.

Comment: That doesn't work since im using gsutil to download from gs into my R on a google vm. With fread its works well, vroom doesn't seem to support the use of gsutil